Optaplanner integration issues - Drools package exception
We are using optaplanner 9.44.0.Final version for our spring project and i am facing below exception
19:19:21,913 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompilerException: [org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (2:121) : cannot find symbol
19:19:21,913 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)   symbol:   class CompiledNetwork
19:19:21,913 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)   location: package org.drools.ancompiler, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (4:30) : package org.drools.base.rule.accessor does not exist, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (6:46) : package org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints does not exist, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (7:29) : package org.drools.base.rule does not exist, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (8:31) : package org.drools.core.reteoo does not exist, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (9:31) : package org.drools.core.reteoo does not exist, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (10:115) : package org.drools.base.rule.accessor does not exist, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (10:191) : package org.drools.core.util.index does not exist, org/drools/ancompiler/Compiledcom_vision360_business_shift_entity_ShiftOccurrenceNetwork31024483268.java (13:109) : package org.drools.base.common does not exist, 

As i understand from this link https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/integration/integration.html#integrationWithSpringBoot
Drools score calculation is currently incompatible with the spring-boot-devtools dependency
And hence  I have written custom ConstraintProvider and configured the same in solverConfig.xml
This doesnt seem to be helping in avoiding the usage of drools package which is causing the above errors
Could you please suggest about this error

Timefold, the continuation of OptaPlanner, doesn't use drools any more (and it's faster).
Use the one-line command to upgrade your code.

Thanks for the quick response , Will try with timefold

The integration was quite quick and issue is resolved , thanks again @geoffrey-de-smet
